# Why does the first statement is skipped inside the while loop?

Tags: java

inside the While-loop , why the first print statement ( which asks the user to enter a number ) is skipped in the first time? I think It's because I don't understand how hasNextInt() method works , I tried though and read about It but really didn't go far.

the easiest solution is to put one print statement outside the loop , I tried it and it worked, but I just wanna know why this statement is skipped in the first Iteration.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int number;
        while(scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
            number = scanner.nextInt();
            scanner.nextLine();
            max = Math.max(max,number);
            min = Math.min(min,number);
        }

        System.out.println("Max number is "+max);
        System.out.println("Min number is "+min);
        scanner.close();
```

Comment: Don't know java API specifically, but probably because it is buffered output and only printed if it has a newline or is explicitly flushed. Is there a `flush` method in `System.out`?

Comment: It isn't skipped, but how is `hasNextInt()` supposed to work if you haven't written anything to the console, yet? _You_ switched input and output, that's not Javas fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) says:

> The next() and hasNext() methods and their primitive-type companion methods (such as nextInt() and hasNextInt()) first skip any input that matches the delimiter pattern, and then attempt to return the next token. Both hasNext and next methods may block waiting for further input

That is, when you get to the `hasNextInt()` call at the start of your first iteration of the `while` loop, the program waits for some input. Because it's waiting, it never gets to your first `System.out.print` statement, until after the first integer is entered.

Answer (score 1):

The call `.hasNextInt()` cannot answer the question you ask it ('is there even a next token in the stream? If yes, is it parseable as an int?') until the user types something.

In general I would advise against using any of the `has` methods. Just have a `while(true)` here.

Presumably you want a way for the user to stop entering numbers; you can either use some sentinel number that means 'okay I am done' (say, -1), or if that's not an option, use `.next()` instead of `.nextInt()`, and check if the entered text is `DONE` or whatnot. If yes, `break;` and if not, `int number = Integer.parseInt(text)`.